# Haskell could not find user defined module

Tags: haskell

I put the files *Lab07* and *Lab07def* in the same path. But when I tried to load Lab07 in ghci, it returns `Could not find module ‘Lab07def’`

```
Prelude> :l K:\lab7\Lab07def.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Lab07def         ( K:\lab7\Lab07def.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
Prelude> :l K:\lab7\Lab07.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Lab07            ( K:\lab7\Lab07.hs, interpreted )

K:\lab7\Lab07.hs:9:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Lab07def’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
9 | import Lab07def
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

This is the first line in *Lab07def*

```
module Lab07def where
```

These are the first two lines in *Lab07*

```
module Lab07 where

import Lab07def
```

They both look good. So what's the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `K:\lab7` to the import search path, with the `-iPATH` option.

```
ghci -iK:\lab7
```

or launch `ghci` from under `lab7`.

Comment: or `:cd K:\lab7` from within `ghci`